# Catch exception from async workflow run on different thread

Tags: asynchronous, f#

```
let failing = async {
    failwith "foo"
}

let test () =
    try
        Async.Start(failing)
    with
    | exn -> printf "caught"
```

This code doesn't catch the exception. How can I start an asynchronous workflow on a separate thread and catch the exception in the main program?

Answer (score 0):

As there is no result awaited, there is no place where the exception could be caught. You need to wrap the computation. One possibility:

```
let failing = async {
    failwith "foo"
}

let test () = 
    async {
        let! res = failing |> Async.Catch
        match res with
        | Choice1Of2 _ -> printf "success"
        | Choice2Of2 exn -> printfn "failed with %s" exn.Message
    } |> Async.Start
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative you start the workflow as a task and use it's methods and properties instead. For example `Task.Result` will rethrow an exception again so this works, and is almost what you tried:

```
let test () = 
   try 
      Async.StartAsTask failing 
      |> fun t -> t.Result
   with _ -> printfn "caught"
```

#### run

```
> test ();;
caught
val it : unit = ()
```

---

### on a differnt thread

sorry - I just saw that you want it on a different thread - in this case you most likely want to use the internal approach RCH gave you - but you could use `ContinueWith` too (although a bit ugly):

```
open System.Threading.Tasks

let test () = 
   (Async.StartAsTask failing).ContinueWith(fun (t : Task<_>) -> try t.Result with _ -> printfn "caught")
```

#### run

```
> test ();;
caught
val it : Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task {AsyncState = null;
                                             CreationOptions = None;
                                             Exception = null;
                                             Id = 3;
                                             IsCanceled = false;
                                             IsCompleted = true;
                                             IsFaulted = false;
                                             Status = RanToCompletion;}
```

---

### without `Async.Catch`

also you don't really need the `Async.Catch`:

```
let test () = 
   async { 
      try 
         do! failing 
      with _ -> printfn "caught" 
   } |> Async.Start
```